# Is there a package that provides simple, isolated circuit symbols?

Tags: circuits

I am looking for a simple way to typeset isolated circuit symbols, such as the following, or closely related, symbols for batteries and capacitors.

[image: battery]
[image: cap]

I am preparing for my thesis defense, and I don't have time to learn how to use a sophisticated package such as `circuitikz`.  But, anyway, I am not needing to draw complete circuits; I just need the isolated symbols (such as circuit symbol "dingbats").

Comment: You might take a look at the pstricks package `pst-circ`, which uses a LaTeX syntax, in particular `§1.2, Dipole macros`  in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Although you mentioned not wanting to use `circuitikz`, here is how you could use said package to draw isolated symbols:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
      \draw (1,0) to [battery] (0,0);
\end{circuitikz}
\begin{circuitikz}
      \draw (0,0) to [capacitor] (1,0);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```